# How to use sparklyr/dplyr n_distinct() in filter() to use conditional filter data in spark dataframe in Azure databricks

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sparklyr, azure-databricks

I have a large dataset in Azure databricks as Spark dataframe and using R code to analyse data. I am transforming the R code that is working in local desktop RStudio to Databricks R code. 
I am trying to filter a large spark dataframe based on the n_distinct(column)>2, to do further analysis.

I have tried to use the working local desktop Rstidio code into the RStudio in Azure databricks.

Need help with transforming "filter( n_distinct(carb)>2)" into spark code

for Rstudio or R notebook in databricks.

```
## working desktop R code
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(mtcars)
## filter the dataset to have only those "cyl" which have number of "carb" more than 2
df.dt1<- df  %>%  group_by(cyl)  %>% filter( n_distinct(carb)>2)

df.dt1
```

```
## Databricks  - RStudio code
set.seed(10)

## use the mtcars dataset
df <- data.frame(mtcars)

## copying to Spark

df.spark <- copy_to(sc, df, "df_spark", overwrite = TRUE)

## filter the dataset to have only those "cyl" which have number of "carb" more than 2
df.dt1<- df.spark %>% group_by(cyl)  %>% filter(dplyr::n_distinct(carb)>2) %>% collect()
```

Error: Window function `distinct()` is not supported by this database

Expected output as below

```
cyl disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  am  gear    carb
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
6   160 110 3.9 2.62    16.46   0   1   4   4
6   160 110 3.9 2.875   17.02   0   1   4   4
6   258 110 3.08    3.215   19.44   1   0   3   1
8   360 175 3.15    3.44    17.02   0   0   3   2
6   225 105 2.76    3.46    20.22   1   0   3   1
8   360 245 3.21    3.57    15.84   0   0   3   4
6   167.6   123 3.92    3.44    18.3    1   0   4   4
6   167.6   123 3.92    3.44    18.9    1   0   4   4
8   275.8   180 3.07    4.07    17.4    0   0   3   3
8   275.8   180 3.07    3.73    17.6    0   0   3   3
```

The resulting dataset will only have records from "cyl" 6 and 8 which have a count of unique "carb" 3 and 4 respectively, while cyl 4 is omitted as it has a unique count of carb 2

```
## actual working code from my dataset in RStudio in Databricks

multi_contract <- Cust_details %>%   

group_by(CustomerID)  %>% 

## filter records for customers having more than one contract
filter(n_distinct(ContractType)>1)
```

The issue with this code is that it takes around 1 hour to process on 1 million records and the resultant dataset is only 41k records.
So there has to be a better way to do this in sparklyr or sparkR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method for counting the distinct observations of some value A within a group B that doesn't use `distinct`:

```
df %>%
  distinct(A, B) %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarise(distinct_A = n())
```

You can inner join the result with the original df on the grouping column `B` to get the desired result.  In terms of your example,

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

mtcars_spark <- sdf_copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars_spark")

keep_cyl <- mtcars_spark %>% 
  distinct(cyl, carb) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(distinct_carb_count = n()) %>%
  filter(distinct_carb_count > 2)

inner_join(keep_cyl, mtcars_spark)
```

Comment: Thanks @zack. I used distinct() and count() instead of summarise. I realised that inner_join is the only option to get the rest of the columns. I was anticipating a simpler code like that in R.